# docker can't run vscodium

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, tiny-core-linux

Mine is a bit of a peculiar situation, I created a dockerfile that "works" if not for some proiblems,
Here is a "working" version:

```
ARG IMGVERS=latest
FROM bensuperpc/tinycore:${IMGVERS}
LABEL maintainer "Vinnie Costante <****@gmail.com>"

ARG DOWNDIR=/tmp/download
ARG INSTDIR=/opt/vscodium
ARG REPOAPI="https://api.github.com/repos/VSCodium/vscodium/releases/latest"

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C PATH="${PATH}:${INSTDIR}/bin/"

RUN tce-load -wic Xlibs nss gtk3 libasound libcups python3.9 tk8.6 \
    && rm -rf /tmp/tce/optional/*
RUN sudo ln -s /lib /lib64 \
    && sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/fonts /etc/fonts \
    && sudo mkdir -p ${DOWNDIR} ${INSTDIR} \
    && sudo chown -R tc:staff ${DOWNDIR} ${INSTDIR}
#COPY VSCodium-linux-x64-1.57.1.tar.gz ${DOWNDIR}/
RUN wget http://192.168.43.6:8000/VSCodium-linux-x64-1.57.1.tar.gz -P ${DOWNDIR}
RUN tar xvf ${DOWNDIR}/VSCodium*.gz -C ${INSTDIR} \
    && rm -rf ${DOWNDIR}
CMD ["codium"]
```

The issues are these:

1. Starting the image with this command vscodium does not start, but entering the shell (adding `/bin/ash` to the end of the docker run) and then running `codium` instead vscodium starts. I tried many ways, even changing the entrypoint, the result is always the same. But if I try to add any other graphic program (like firefox) and replace the argument of the `CMD` instruction inside the dockerfile, everything works as it should.

   ```
   docker run -it --rm \
   --net=host \
   --env="DISPLAY=unix${DISPLAY}" \
   --workdir /home/tc \
   --volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" \
   --name tc \
   tinycodium
   ```
2. the last two versions of codium (1.58.0 and 1.58.1) don't work at all on docker but they start normally on the same distro not containerized. I tried installing other dependencies but nothing worked. Right now I don't know how to understand what's wrong with these two new versions.
3. I don't know how to set a volume to save codium data, I tried something like this `--volume=/home/vinnie/docker:/home/tc` but there are always problems with user/group permissions. I've also tried booting the container as user by adding it to the docker group but there's always a mess with permissions. If someone could explain me how to proceed, the directories I want to save are these:

   ```
   /home/tc/.vscode-oss
   /home/tc/.cache/mesa_shader_cache
   /home/tc/.config/VSCodium
   /home/tc/.config/glib-2.0/settings
   /home/tc/.local/share
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try running `codium --verbose` and see if the container starts